# Is short /ɪ/ or long /i:/ being used for the pronunciation of "Mid" on Cambridge Online Dictionary

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

To my ears, the Cambridge dictionary pronounces the word "Mid" /mɪd/ really like /mi:d/ for **British accent**. So the long /i:/ is being used instead of the short /ɪ/. Compare:

- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mid
- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/meet

Did I hear it wrong or is it the pronunciation is not correct?

Comment: I'm very surprised! You're completely right. The vowel that speaker has used is too close. It's not a proper KIT vowel at all, and the audio needs redoing :)

Answer (score -1):

The Cambridge dictionary has pronounced the word correctly. (**mid** as /**mɪd**/)

/ɪ/  (NOT /iː/)

/ɪ/ - it sit did still lip pill **mid**

/iː/ - eat seat deed steal leap peel **meed**

Comment: No! It hasn't!!! OP is completely correct. The vowel produced is way too close/high to be a typical realisation of the RP KIT vowel..

Comment: Are you listening to the UK or the US pronunciation? The UK one sounds like *mead*, while the US one sounds correct.

Comment: I have no problems with the US pronunciation, it's 100% correct for me. But the British is the one that causes trouble to me.

Comment: @Mohammad do you hear any the difference between the two words I provided in question (for UK accent)? BTW, I sent the audio only of the word "mid" to my friend who is a British citizen and asked him what word he heard and he said "meat".

Comment: @KhanhTran Yes, I did the same. Everyone said *meat, meet*!